# HIbernate not returning results when passing class name in createCriteria or get

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I can't for the life of me figure out why Hibernate is not returning results or even executing the query when I pass the class name into the createCriteria() or get() methods.  I've looked everything over and don't know what I'm missing.  My jsp is calling a service, which calls the DAO, which retrieves the data.

When I execute this statement, it does not work, in fact it doesn't even run the SQL at all (as it's not displayed in the console):

```
List<StyleChooser> temp = sessionFactory.openSession().createCriteria(StyleChooser.class).list();
```

However when I run this, it works (console displays Hibernate: select * from css):

```
List<StyleChooser> temp = sessionFactory.openSession().createSQLQuery("select * from css").list();
```

StyleChooser.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="css")
public class StyleChooser {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="ID")
public Integer id;

@Column(name="HrefColor")
public String hrefColor;

@Column(name="ButtonBackColor")
public String buttonBackColor;

@Column(name="ButtonTextColor")
public String buttonTextColor;

@Column(name="TextSize")
public Integer textSize;

@Transient
public CommonsMultipartFile file;

public CommonsMultipartFile getFile() {
    return file;
}
public void setFile(CommonsMultipartFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getHrefColor() {
    return hrefColor;
}
public void setHrefColor(String hrefColor) {
    this.hrefColor = hrefColor;
}
public String getButtonBackColor() {
    return buttonBackColor;
}
public void setButtonBackColor(String buttonBackColor) {
    this.buttonBackColor = buttonBackColor;
}
public String getButtonTextColor() {
    return buttonTextColor;
}
public void setButtonTextColor(String buttonTextColor) {
    this.buttonTextColor = buttonTextColor;
}
public Integer getTextSize() {
    return textSize;
}
public void setTextSize(Integer textSize) {
    this.textSize = textSize;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  Guess it might help if I scan the packages in my sessionFactory.